# Existence of Deligne's tensor product of finite abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I'm trying to show that for the categories $A$-Mod and $B$-Mod (where $A$ and $B$ are finite-dimensional algebras), we can define ($A$-Mod)$\boxtimes (B$-Mod) $= (A\otimes B)$-Mod. I'm following [Etingof, Gelaki, Nikshych, and Ostrik, "Tensor Categories"](https://math.mit.edu/~etingof/egnobookfinal.pdf), section 1.11 (they work with comodules for coalgebras, but I only need Deligne's tensor product for finite abelian categories), where their definition of Deligne's tensor product is as follows:

"There is a bifunctor $\boxtimes : \mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}\boxtimes\mathcal{D}$ which is right exact in both variables and and is such that for any right exact in both
variables bifunctor $F : \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{A}$ there exists a unique right exact functor $\overline{F} : \mathcal{C} \boxtimes \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{A}$ satisfying $\overline{F} \circ \boxtimes = F$."

I can see how the functor $\otimes : A\text{-Mod} \times B\text{-Mod} \to (A\otimes B)\text{-Mod}$ is right exact in both variables. What I want to say is something like the following: Any right exact functor commutes with cokernels and direct sums, and any $A$-module can be written as the cokernel of some map $\phi : A^{\oplus n} \to A^{\oplus m}$. Thus, any right exact in both variables bifunctor $F : A\text{-Mod}\times B\text{-Mod} \to \mathcal{A}$ is uniquely determined by it's value on $(A, B)$, and any right exact functor $\overline{F} : (A\otimes B)\text{-Mod} \to \mathcal{A}$ is uniquely determined by its value on $A\otimes B$, so setting $\overline{F}(A\otimes B) = F(A, B)$ gives the required unique functor.

The problem with this is that cokernels and direct sums are only defined up to (unique) isomorphism, not equality, so I can't claim that $F$ is "uniquely determined by it's value on $(A, B)$" up to equality (or the equivalent statement for $\overline{F}$). The original definition of Deligne's tensor product seems aggressive when it says that the functors have to be equal, and indeed the nlab page which references EGNO says that the functors are "equivalent" (though I'm not entirely sure what they mean by that). If I change the definition to say that "there exists a unique (up to natural isomorphism) right exact functor $\overline{F} : \mathcal{C} \boxtimes \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{A}$ satisfying $\overline{F} \circ \boxtimes \cong F$" though it seems to become a lot more difficult to prove that $\otimes$ satisfies this condition. For example, I can't say "any right exact functor $\overline{F} : (A\otimes B)\text{-Mod} \to \mathcal{A}$ is uniquely determined by its value on $A\otimes B$", I only know that once we fix $\overline{F}(A\otimes B)$ we know the isomorphism class of the image of anything else in $(A\otimes B)\text{-Mod}$, which feels a lot weaker.

I can't immediately see how to fix my argument, if it's fixable, or if my concern about the equality in the definition of $\boxtimes$ is valid. I also can't seem to find any proof online to compare mine to, since every source I look at just says it's easy. Any help would be greatly appreciated!